# Email doesn't get sent properly

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm using outlook 2007 as my email client, configured using imap. Everything works well, usually. However, I have been having a periodic problem where my emails do not get sent and end up in the sent folder located under personal folders. Most of the time I send an email, no problem, the the recipient get it and the message is saved in the imap sent folder. But there have been about 5 occasions since August that messages appear to get sent, but are never delivered and end up in the wrong sent mail folder.

I just have one email account connected on this computer and through outlook, in account settings the type is listed as IMAP/SMTP.

This incident presented itself yesterday, again. Up until this point I was under the impression that these emails were not being sent. Today, however I received a reply to the one which occurred yesterday. It would appear then, as though the emails are being sent, just saved to the wrong folder, occasionally...I have double checked the correct folder is selected in account settings and usually, it saves there no problem.

Comment: Do you have more than one mail transport enabled?